# Selecting an entire row but the first column in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code and what loop does is "copies" all the data from 1 row on worksheet1 and "pastes" it on worksheet2. the problem that I have is that I need the row to be pasted in worksheet2 but starting from column B and not column A.

```
Do While rowCounter < 2200
    If Cells(rowCounter, colCounter).Value <> "AP Statistics Summary" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Throughput Per AP").Rows(throughputAP).Offset(1, 0).Value = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(rowCounter).Value
        throughputAP = throughputAP + 1
    End If
    rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
Loop
```

the issue happens on this line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("worksheet2").Rows(throughputAP).Offset(1, 0).Value = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(rowCounter).Value
```

so the code runs ok but the data gets copied to worksheet2 starting from column A and I need it to start from column B

help please!

Comment: I'm not shure if it works, but have you tried: 

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("worksheet2").Rows(throughputAP).Offset(1, 0).Value = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(rowCounter) **.Offset(1, 0)** .Value

Comment: @tretom hi mate, no, it didnt work..... same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to resize the source row to be one column less wide than the full row, then copy that to column A (i.e. copying B:XFD to A:XFC):

```
'Using a With simply to shorten the code
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(rowCounter)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("worksheet2").Rows(throughputAP + 1).Resize(1, .Columns.Count - 1).Value = _
                  .Resize(1, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(0, 1).Value
End With
```

Or, if you are trying to copy A:XFC to B:XFD you can do

```
'Using a With simply to shorten the code
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(rowCounter)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("worksheet2").Rows(throughputAP + 1).Resize(1, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = _
                  .Resize(1, .Columns.Count - 1).Value
End With
```

Or, if you are happy to hardcode the column letters, you can use

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("worksheet2").Rows(throughputAP + 1).Range("A1:XFC1").Value = _
                  ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(rowCounter).Range("B1:XFD1").Value
```

or switching the "A1:XFC1" and "B1:XFD1" if you want to go the opposite direction

(Those bits of code replacing the line you are having problems with.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it will copy the `EntireRow` and uses `PasteSpecial xlValues` to paste only the values.

```
Do While rowCounter < 2200
    If Cells(rowCounter, colCounter).Value <> "AP Statistics Summary" Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(rowCounter).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Throughput Per AP").Rows(throughputAP).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlValues
        throughputAP = throughputAP + 1
    End If
    rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
Loop
```

**However**, in your case, I would replace your `Do While` with `For rowCounter`.

Also, use fully qualified `Worksheets`, and not `ActiveSheet`.

**Version 2 of your code**

```
For rowCounter = 2 To 2200 ' <-- start from 2 (or your start row)
    With Worksheets("YourSheetName") ' <-- put here you sheet's name instead of ActiveSheet
        If .Cells(rowCounter, colCounter).Value <> "AP Statistics Summary" Then
            .Rows(rowCounter).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Throughput Per AP").Rows(throughputAP).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlValues
            throughputAP = throughputAP + 1
        End If
    End With
Next rowCounter
```